# What is iLifeAssetManagement, and can I delete it?

Tags: macos, filesystem, ilife, library

I have 5 GB of stuff in `~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement` and I'd like the space back. What is this stuff and how can I reduce its footprint?

Comment: I found the same thing (lots of space being taken up by ilifeassetmanagement). I run Aperture; turning off My Photo Stream immediately reduced the size of ilifeassetmanagement by several GB (Aperture/Preferences/iCloud ... uncheck My Photo Stream).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can delete it. I would make a backup of your Mac before deleting anything in ~/Library just in case you run into corruption.

This folder contains iCloud synced photos from your PhotoStream, so you might just have the folder fill up again unless you want to poke at that folder and make sure you turn off iCloud syncing before you do the pruning.

- [Does PhotoStream sync to my Mac when iPhoto is not open?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45560/does-photostream-sync-to-my-mac-when-iphoto-is-not-open)

Deleting things from the iCloud photo stream directly will reduce the size footprint on all your devices so that's what I'd recommend in this particular case. You can sort things by size in Finder, so that might help you see if just a few large videos are responsible or if you instead have hundreds of small photos all adding up.

Comment: Update to this question: Now that 10.10.3 has been released with the new photos app and the new streaming agent: can I now throw this away for good? Where does the new infrastructure store its data?

Comment: @Arne oddly - the new infrastructure is sorely buggy. I can't get pages or keynote to see any photos from Photos.app on one of my two Macs. I'm working with Apple support, but that question might be a great one to ask on the site in general. Even though I don't have an answer yet, someone else might. It should work and does on one Mac - but it's buggy IMO.

Comment: @Arne I've posted a new [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/182157/10193) asking if the folder can be deleted. The new infrastructure doesn't store its data on your Mac separately from your Photos.app library, as was the case with PhotoStream and iPhoto. It doesn't need to as it's all stored in the cloud. And FWIW, I've found iCloud Photo Library super robust.

Comment: I delete without making backup (no more disk space) and I had no problem! :-)